# Converting code from Netezza to Snowflake stored procedures

Tags: sql, for-loop, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, netezza

I'm currently attempting to convert some code from Netezza code stored procedure to Snowflake stored procedure. There is one particular piece that I'm trying to convert by using a SQL cursor for loop.

The Netezza code is this

```
FOR counter IN 1 .. l_count LOOP
```

I was originally attempting to do in snowflake

```
let c1 cursor for counter;
FOR l_count in c1 do
```

And I also declared counter as counter RESULTSET;

Yet this doesn't seem to be working and I tried alternating it in many different ways but cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake also supports [FOR LOOP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/for):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(i INT);

DECLARE 
   l_counter INT := 5;
BEGIN
  FOR counter IN 1 TO l_counter DO
      INSERT INTO t(i) SELECT :counter;
  END FOR;
END;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
--I
--1
--2
--3
--4
--5
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just realized that too. I had just assumed that it needed to be converted in a specific way, but I managed to fix the problem. Thanks again!